# Performance tuning world wide?

Tags: performance, web-server

I am working on a website that is used by people all over the world.  Currently we have a web server that is in Oregon and a database sever that is in Chicago.

When users from the US access the site it has pretty good load speeds.  Recently we've been getting complaints from users in far away places of the world saying that the site loads slowly for them.  I began [running some tests](http://www.webpagetest.org/) and it looks like if you hit the site from those countries it is easy to see load times of 5-7 seconds (compared to 1-2 seconds in the US).

Is this type of slowness to be expected considering where our servers are living?

What are some steps I should consider to speed up access in areas that are geographically distant from our servers?

Answer (score 2):

> What are some steps I should consider to speed up access in areas that
>   are geographically distant from our servers?

Move your server(s) closer. Seriously, there's no rocket science here. In lieu of moving your servers closer, you may consider using a CDN, but depending on the nature of your site, that may or may not make much of a difference.

Comment: Very interesting.  Just for my own understanding - why does the distance between the web and database server have a dramatic difference on performance in distant locations but not closer ones?

Comment: @AbeMiessler It doesn't. It just degrades overall performance, so it's something to consider changing.

Comment: @AbeMiessler, when your web server sends a query, let's say it takes your database server 5ms (this is a complex query) to run.  If your database is a 1ms ping away, running this query adds about 6 ms to the overall page load time. Now, let's say that database server is 60ms away, running that query now takes 65 ms, not including the time taken to encrypt that connection, because you don't want raw user data flying about the Internet. Assuming you have to run four queries to load a page, and there's a 60ms latency, you can see how it would quickly add up to 180 extra ms just to get the data.

Answer (score 2):

You really need millisecond latency between your web server and database server, both to speed up the site and reduce load on both servers. Especially so if you use encryption between the two. Which you do; I hope for the sake of your users.

If doing this doesn't speed the site up sufficiently enough from Eurpoe to satisfy you, you could look at either implementing CloudFlare or Cloud Front, or you could get your own server running Varnish or Apache Traffic Server (the latter supports SSL), to cache your site in Eurpoe while still hosting the content in the USA.

Either way, move that database server!

Comment: That will affect the time to deliver all requests.  If off-shore users are using the same web and db servers as on-shore ones, then the latency between web and db won't be different for them.